# How do I get back my suspend option in Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome, 12.10, shutdown, panel

With the new version of Gnome Shell in Ubuntu 12.10 they turned [most peoples issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71283/where-is-the-gnome-shell-shutdown-options/71287#71287) around by just displaying the *shutdown* option which becomes *suspend* on pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

How do I get back my beloved suspend option?

Comment: keyboard shortcut: https://askubuntu.com/questions/652978/how-to-create-keyboard-shortcut-which-initiates-suspend