# Hibernate in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: hibernate

I know this question has already been asked but none of those methods worked for me. I tried

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

but it shuts down my pc. I know this means hibernate isn't supported but I could hibernate on this pc itself on Ubuntu 16.04 before i upgraded to 18.04. So I'm pretty sure that hibernate is supported.

```
$ swapon --summary

Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda6                               partition   4194300 0   -2
```

Comment: Do you have a swap file or a swap partition setup to allow for hibernation?  Edit your question and include the output of `swapon -s`.  Thank you!

Comment: Hibernation involves the system shutting down and turning off, though it should look different from the usual shutdown process. If you get a clean boot when you switch on again, you may need to set a kernel parameter for resume. See [How can I hibernate on Ubuntu 16.04?](//askubuntu.com/q/768136)

Comment: On my 18.04 Hibernation is grayed out - Suspend seems to work all right, I have a swap file a bit larger than the ram!

Comment: I have increased my ram. Will that affect this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04 can't resume after hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034185/ubuntu-18-04-cant-resume-after-hibernate)

Answer (score 3):

Try this way.

```
sudo apt-get install hibernate
```

After that just type in terminal `sudo hibernate`
This way work for me

Comment: By this system get hibernate but start in black screen, I wait few minutes but had to power off/on pc :(

Comment: I installed this app but it just went black for a few seconds and then the screen came back.not even power down.  Nothing accomplished.

Comment: Same happened to me - i.e. got stuck on black screen and pc was unresponsive to all inputs - had to resort to long push-down-on-Power-button to reboot.  Hmmmmm