# Ubuntu 18.04.2 cannot continue its work after the laptop sleeps!

Tags: graphics

I use Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS in ASUS‌ laptop with processor AMD® Fx-9830p radeon r7, 12 compute cores 4c+8g × 4 with Graphics AMD® Carrizo. When I‌ close my laptop to sleep and after sometimes, I open it, sometimes I can continue working but sometimes it shows blank and sometimes it shows squares with different colors! Hence, I have to shut down my laptop and turn it on again. Is there any correction for it?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! When this happens can you log into a terminal instead with Ctrl-Alt-F3 and issue the command `dmesg | grep rror` and then [edit] that info into your post? Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I have examed. Ctrl-Alt-F3 does not work and shows nothing. I have restarted again.

Comment: Ok, how about you [edit] the output of `sudo grep rror /var/log/syslog` and the output of `uname -a` into your post then.

Comment: when I type "sudo grep rror /var/log/syslog" I‌ receive lots of messages, such as: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.

Comment: org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1861]: [2295:2303:0219/093916.275089:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(964)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
JS ERROR: Exception in callback for signal: activate: Error: Error invoking IBus.set_global_engine_async: Expected function for callback argument callback, got undefined#012setEngine@resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/ibusManager.js:207:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012activateInputSource@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/keyboard.js:490:13#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:

Comment: when I type "uname -a" I‌ receive: Linux safa-X550IU 4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Please make a habit of [edit]ing requested information into your post as [comments can be deleted for numerous reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222624/when-are-all-comments-deleted) and not everyone reads them.

Comment: I should inform that my laptop has dual boot, one is windows 10 and the other is Ubuntu 18.04. It is possible that this error related to this dual boot. But, I have not found the answer yet!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04 can't resume after hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034185/ubuntu-18-04-cant-resume-after-hibernate)