# hibernate after image load from swap Laptop starts new

Tags: 18.04, hibernate

I'm running  bionic  with xfce4-session on

```
sudo dmidecode -t1
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: 2350B58
    Version: ThinkPad T430
    Serial Number: PBVVBLH
    UUID: CDCB8A01-5190-11CB-9490-98976E1F3194
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_2350
    Family: ThinkPad T430
```

on bios mode with tlp. Nothing is encrypted.

```
pkexec  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xfce4/session/xfsm-shutdown-helper --hibernate
```

and with `sudo systemctl hibernate`

In both cases, ubuntu tells load successfully image, suddenly I see thinkpad uefisplash as the Notebook lost power.

```
   echo; for i in --suspend --hibernate --suspend-hybrid; do pm-is-supported $i && echo "$(echo $i | tr [:lower:] [:upper:] | tr -d -) is supported"; done; echo 

SUSPEND is supported
HIBERNATE is supported
SUSPENDHYBRID is supported
```

Running Kernel and options.

```
 cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-55-generic root=UUID=0ddc8e0a-4b8a-479c-9502-5478ed3c4036 ro noplymouth resume=UUID=927f38a0-c962-47de-9361-f1730032704e
```

and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume 
RESUME=UUID=927f38a0-c962-47de-9361-f1730032704e`

```
    cat /etc/fstab | grep swap | egrep -v '#'
UUID=927f38a0-c962-47de-9361-f1730032704e none  swap    sw              0       0
```

I forgot [I try this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034185/ubuntu-18-04-cant-resume-after-hibernate?rq=1)

```
cat /sys/power/image_size 
1535959040
```

and

```
cat /sys/power/state
freeze mem disk
```

also

```
cat /sys/power/disk 
[platform] shutdown reboot suspend test_resume
```

Kernel from ukuu `linux-image-5.0.20-050020-generic` also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, try another kernel from ukuu for now it is working.

```
uname -a
Linux beelzemon 5.0.21-050021-generic #201906040731 SMP Tue Jun 4 07:45:51 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```