# apt-listchanges crasht. How can I get the E-Mail?

Tags: apt, python, email, exim

I made an `apt full-upgrade` it updates thermald.

Normally, I get an E-Mail from apt-listchanges over exim4 to localhost. For 2 days it was working.

```
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 thermald i386 1.7.0-5ubuntu5 [203 kB]
Fetched 203 kB in 0s (519 kB/s) 
apt-listchanges: Changelogs werden gelesen...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 281, in <module>
    main(config)
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 145, in main
    _send_email(changes, lambda: _("apt-listchanges: changelogs for %s") % hostname)
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 267, in _send_email
    apt_listchanges.mail_changes(config, changes, subject_getter())
  File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/apt_listchanges.py", line 65, in mail_changes
    'subject': subject})
  File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/ALCLog.py", line 36, in info
    print(_("apt-listchanges: %(msg)s") % {'msg': msg}, file=sys.stdout);
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 73: ordinal not in range(128)
(Reading database ... 381751 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../thermald_1.7.0-5ubuntu5_i386.deb ...
Unpacking thermald (1.7.0-5ubuntu5) over (1.7.0-5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up thermald (1.7.0-5ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
```

pythonversions

```
python --version
Python 2.7.15+
```

and

```
python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
```

I'm not sure which information are important.

```
hostnamectl 
   Static hostname: beelzemon
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: acaecd284840b500117c175c571c9e28
           Boot ID: c583ba22cd6c4abdbf6627d82e26283d
  Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.0.21-050021-generic
      Architecture: x86
```

I need this Ukuu-Kernel for hibernate. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161635/hibernate-after-image-load-from-swap-laptop-starts-new)
How can I get the E-Mail from apt-listchanges again?

```
 head -n36 /usr/share/apt-listchanges/ALCLog.py
# vim:set fileencoding=utf-8 et ts=4 sts=4 sw=4:
#
#   apt-listchanges - Show changelog entries between the installed versions
#                     of a set of packages and the versions contained in
#                     corresponding .deb files
#
#   Copyright (C) 2016       Robert Luberda  <robert@debian.org>
#
#   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#   (at your option) any later version.
#
#   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#   GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public
#   License along with this program; if not, write to the Free
#   Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston,
#   MA 02111-1307 USA
#

import sys

from ALChacks import _

def error(msg):
    print(_("apt-listchanges: %(msg)s") % {'msg': msg}, file=sys.stderr);

def warning(msg):
    print(_("apt-listchanges warning: %(msg)s") % {'msg': msg}, file=sys.stderr);

def info(msg):
    print(_("apt-listchanges: %(msg)s") % {'msg': msg}, file=sys.stdout);
```

Comment: The system wants to e-mail you a text that contains a non-ascii character 0xFC, or a superscript n (`ⁿ`). Python does not output text from a character set that it doesn't understand.  You may want to include line 36 of the Python script `/usr/share/apt-listchanges/ALCLog.py` in your question; we may be able to help you correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was wrong. I installt the previous version von thermald and make the upgrade again.

```
    sudo apt upgrade thermald
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  thermald
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/203 kB of archives.
After this operation, 21.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
apt-listchanges: Changelogs werden gelesen...
(Reading database ... 310828 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../thermald_1.7.0-5ubuntu5_i386.deb ...
Unpacking thermald (1.7.0-5ubuntu5) over (1.7.0-5ubuntu1) ...
Setting up thermald (1.7.0-5ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
```

I hope this was only hiccup :D