# Hibernate caused ubuntu boot failure

Tags: boot, 18.04, raid, hibernate

I run Ubuntu 18.04 (Gnome Desktop) and attempted to test hibernation via `sudo systemctl hibernate`

Oddly the screen blanked out and the pc restarted into my BIOs. What follows is a blanking cursor on a black screen. Running `Ctrl + Alt+ Del' restarts the machine.

I have no idea what happened, this was the only command that was run. Seems it has corrupted my file storage.

Would deeply appreciate any insights as I have no idea how to fix it to revert back to normal. I can only access BIOs.

The system was configured as Raid 5

Answer (score 0):

This class of problems is extremely frustrating to debug without a second computer attached and a serial console (your MB probably does have headers for it, if not a USB-Serial is better than nothing) on the target machine to stream kernel dmesg logs with maximum verbosity.

The following troubleshooting guide will help you get started:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1038856/6045

A lot of it boils down to competition for free memory to flush everything without gumming up the system into a live lock situation.

The more complex your data storage setup is, the more potential problems you're going to have.

If you have a spare disk handy try a bare install to it with nothing fancy (ext4, noraid) and an actual swap partition to see if the motherboard/chipset itself can perform hibernation.

The [fwts tool](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FirmwareTestSuite/Reference) has a mechanism for automatically testing suspend | hibernate. If you can successfully return from hibernate (S4) 100 times, I would call the system stable.